# Default Accept and Content Type For CXF Service

Tags: web-services, cxf, restful-url

I have developed few restful webservice in cxf. The service returns json or xml response based on Accept header type sent by user. But if user doesn't specify the header it defaults to xml. Can I change it to default json response always if user doesn't specify Accept header type?